# Conditions for affine transform on $\mathbb{R}^3$ to be a contraction

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces, fractals

I am reading about affine transformations used in fractal image compression, they are of the form:

$$ w \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a  &  b  &  0 \\
                                                      c  &  d  &  0 \\
                                                      0  &   0 &  s \\
                            \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z  \\ \end{pmatrix}  +      \begin{pmatrix} e \\ f  \\ o   \\ \end{pmatrix}$$

Let $$ A =  \begin{pmatrix} a  &  b  &  0 \\
                                                      c  &  d  &  0 \\
                                                      0  &   0 &  s \\
                            \end{pmatrix}  $$

$w$ must be a contraction: spatial contraction (acting on the plane: $x$- and $y$-coordinates) and also a contraction in the $z$-direction.  Some of the conditions for $w$ to be a contraction (that I found  in different  sources)  are:

1. $\| A \|_{2} < 1$
2. $ |s| < 1$ and   $\left\| \begin{pmatrix} a  &  b   \\   c  &  d   \\ \end{pmatrix} \right\|_{2}  < 1$
3. $ |\det (A)| < 1$   (as a condition for spatial contraction)

What are the right conditions for  spatial contractivity and z-contractivity ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The two norm is definitely the preferred measure of contractivity - practically by definition. By contrast, the absolute value of the determinant may be less than one, yet the matrix may still fail to be a contraction. For example, if $$M=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&1/4\end{pmatrix},$$ then, $\det(M)=1/2$ but $M\langle 1,0 \rangle=\langle 2,0 \rangle$.

Comment: I think that user122=user121.